# Draw ecg graph dynamically with gap between x axis interval would be 25mm while printing on paper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I have made a chart that export in PDF. But client wants that gap between each x axis interval will be 25 mm as it is ECG graph and gap between each y axis should be 5mm when printed on paper.

I have a CSV file which contains  x axis data in milliseconds and y axis data, I have to show x axis in seconds with interval of 1 sec. I have break the CSV data in list so that each graph can contain only 7 sec in x axis. Functionality is working fine, but how can I adjust the graph so that while printing on paper the ECG graph can shows x axis interval gap with 25 mm. Is there any third party tool by which it can be achieved or can be shown like it has been draw on graph paper( graph background or ECG graph background) with 25mm /Sec on X Axis

As it has to be export so I can't use java script or jquery because it omits  tag.

below is my code

```
private Byte[] GetChart(List<string[]> data)
{
    var chart = new Chart
    {
        Width = 1000,
        Height = 450,
        RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag,
        AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All,
        TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High
    };

    chart.Titles.Add(string.Empty);
    chart.Titles[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16f);
    chart.ChartAreas.Add("");
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Speed:25/Sec";
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Gain:10mm/mV";
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12f);
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12f);
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10f);
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart.Series.Add("");
    chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        double xval = Convert.ToDouble(item[0]) / 1000;
        chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xval, item[1]);
    }
    using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())
    {
        chart.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        return chartimage.GetBuffer();
    }
}

public ActionResult ExportDataToPDF()
{
    //Create the PDF Document
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    pdfDoc.SetMargins(30f, 30f, 60f, 30f);

    //open the stream
    pdfDoc.Open();
    List<string[]> data = GetCSVData();
    if (data.Count > 0)
    {
        double d = 0;
        double.TryParse(data.LastOrDefault()[0], out d);
        d = d / 1000;
        double totalchart = Math.Ceiling(d / 7);
        long startrange = 0; long endrange = 7000;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalchart; i++)
        {
            var lst = data.Where(e => Convert.ToDouble(e[0]) > startrange && Convert.ToDouble(e[0]) <= endrange).ToList();
            var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(GetChart(lst));
            image.ScalePercent(50f);
            pdfDoc.Add(image);
            startrange = endrange;
            endrange = endrange + 7000;
        }
    }
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + "filename=EcgReport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
    return View();


}

public List<string[]> GetCSVData()
{
    var csv = new List<string[]>(); // or, List<YourClass>
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/ecg_asc1011100000318g_20121115144350032.csv");
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
    string[] myColumns = new string[90];
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        csv.Add(line.Split(',')); // or, populate YourClass          
    }
    return csv;
}
```

Comment: Is there is no one who can help?

Comment: there's just too much going on in your question for us to reproduce and answer. You've got a CSV file that we don't have that you're loading into a `Chart` which appears to be a `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` and then applying some domain-specific logic parsing CSV into the chart and saving it to an image and bringing it into iTextSharp. So is you're question about how to make the chart different? iTextSharp only sees an image so it can't help you (unless stretching the image is acceptable). Whatever the question is, make a very short sample that we can reproduce.

Comment: I have tried to stretch the chart but when i print it on paper it shows the gap only 23 mm unable to manage is to 25 mm